# requests-HTML: Ввод текста в input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всех приветствую. Столкнулся с проблемой в библиотеке requests-HTML при попытке ввода текста.
С помощью r.html.find можно найти элемент, но есть ли возможность с ним взаимодействовать, присваивать значение value или click по кнопке?
Прошу помощи у знатоков. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Нет, в том и штука. Селениум, увы, ужасно медленный. Библиотека не requests а requests-html. Она использует что-то вроде безголового браузера, по тому что я понял

Comment: Да, действительно. Простите, я неправильно понял вопрос.